# Substitution of aryl bromide in synthesis of a chelator

Tags: organic-chemistry, catalysis

Hello I am currently working on a synthesis of a chelator for the synthesis of a photosensitizer for photodynamic therapy. My instructor wants me to do following synthesis procedure:

[image]

My problem is, the conditions for the last step are not yet known. How can ipso-substitution of the bromide be carried out? One version we tried was a copper-catalyzed process (CuI (1 eq), DMEDA (0.2 eq, cat.), NaN3 (2 eq.)) which only worked in 10% yield (fragment could only be seen in ESI).

How can the last reaction be sucessfully done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protect your phenols (silyl ethers should be OK). Do a metal-halogen exchange with nBuLi or iPrMgCl to make the aryllithium or Grignard and react this with tosyl azide. Work up with sodium pyrophosphate as described in this JACS [paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jo01263a047)

Also see this Angewandte [paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/anie.201912419) for a recent example which has useful references

Comment: I will try the protection + JACS method. Thanks!

Comment: Update: I couldn't do the method. I ordered tosyl azide from Sigma and wow they sure take their time, it's been more than two weeks! I tried the method with this method: https://www.thieme-connect.com/products/ejournals/abstract/10.1055/s-2005-872248 , however, I couldn't get it to work somehow. Either my substrate is too fragile regarding elevated temperatures, or my batch is too big. I tried the bromide and the iodide. Any thoughts (while I am still waiting for tosyl azide)?

Comment: Were the phenol groups protected during the reaction?  If they were not they are acidic enough to convert your sodium azide to hydrazoic acid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no they were not protected, but just in case I used an excess of NaN3. I thought this shouldn’t be a problem. Also the deprotonation should be unfavorable due to the low acidity of the phenol, and the weak basicity of the azide ion, or am I wrong?

Comment: pKa of phenols is around 10, and if the azide gets protonated the hydrazoic acid is volatile and will be lost from the reaction meixture. The phenols can also complex your copper catalyst. I think it worth trying the reaction again with the phenols protected.

Comment: That is true, the hydrazoic acid has a boiling point of 37°C. I also tried the reaction, stirring at room temperature, but didn't work it up yet; maybe it worked there. I will try to work that up today. I also have a batch of protected phenols sitting at my bench